# Updating document on change of variable freezes checkbox

Tags: firebase, swiftui

When I press the checkbox, using the code below, it updates the data in firebase, but when I try to uncheck, it takes two presses before it shows it as unpressed, even though on the first press, it updates in firebase.

```
struct ReportsUI: View {

  @State var hasbeenbilled = false

  var body: some View {
        VStack {
          VStack {
            HStack {
              VStack {
                ZStack {
                  VStack {
                  }
                  .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                  .background(hasbeenbilled == true ? .blue : colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
                  .cornerRadius(5)
                  if hasbeenbilled {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                      .foregroundColor(.white)
                  }
                }
              }
              .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
              .background(.blue)
              .cornerRadius(5)
              .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                  hasbeenbilled.toggle()
                }
                let document = db.collection("Flights").document("\(flightnum)")
                document.updateData([
                  "hasBeenBilled": hasbeenbilled,
                ]) { err in
                  if let err = err {
                    print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                      } else {
                    print("Document successfully updated")
                      }
                    }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        .padding(.leading)
}
}
```

I tried removing the firebase update code, and it worked perfectly, except I need it to update in firebase. What can I do?

Comment: You're missing some important context here -- what you have isn't enough to represent the issue. The code you've shown so far doesn't rely on Firebase at all for its state, so there's likely an external factor affecting things.

Comment: That doesn't make since, as removing the firebase code makes it toggle like normal.

Comment: You need to identify when the variable actually updates in firebase right now you are fighting asynchronous and synchronous code.

Comment: also, why are you using         `VStack { VStack { HStack { VStack { ZStack { VStack {
`
?, lol.

Comment: Like @loremipsum said, there's some external factor at work here

Comment: It does update in firebase, gets checked in the app, and then immediately gets unchecked. When I press it again though, it checks fine, updates again, which is the same data, and when I uncheck, it updates in firebase and displays that in the app. @GrandSirr because there is more code, but irrelevant to the question

Comment: "gets checked in the app, and then immediately gets unchecked" that's the relevant part of the code. You're not showing the part that's causing the issue.

Comment: I don't know what's causing that. When I remove the firebase code it doesn't do that so I thought that was the issue. In the preview provider, which doesn't run the firebase code, it checks and unchecks just fine